# "Undefined control sequence" for \section when using arXiv template - Why is it so?

Tags: sectioning, errors, numbering, compilation-error, undefined

```
\documentclass[10pt,leqno]{amsart}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\baselineskip=16pt

\usepackage{indentfirst,csquotes}

\topmargin= .5cm
\textheight= 20cm
\textwidth= 32cc
\baselineskip=16pt

\evensidemargin= .9cm
\oddsidemargin= .9cm

\usepackage{amssymb,amsthm,amsmath}
\usepackage{xcolor,paralist,hyperref,titlesec,fancyhdr,etoolbox}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[]
\newtheorem{definition}[theorem]{Definition}
\newtheorem{example}[theorem]{Example}
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition}
\newtheorem{corollary}[theorem]{Corollary}
\newtheorem{conjecture}[theorem]{Conjecture}

\titleformat{\section}[display]{\normalfont\huge\bfseries\centering}{\centering\chaptertitlename\thechapter}{10pt}{\Large}
\titlespacing*{\section}{0pt}{0ex}{0ex}

\hypersetup{ colorlinks=true, linkcolor=black, filecolor=black, urlcolor=black }
\def\proof{\noindent {\it Proof. $\, $}}
\def\endproof{\hfill $\Box$ \vskip 5 pt }

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\title{Title} %%%%%%%%%%%%
\author[Initial Surname]{Author}
\date{\today}
\address{Address}
\email{example@mail.com}
\maketitle

\let\thefootnote\relax
\footnotetext{MSC2020: Primary 00A05, Secondary 00A66.} %%%%%%%%%%

\begin{abstract}
    Abstract 
\end{abstract} %%%%%%%%%

\bigskip

\section{Basic definitions}

\noindent \lipsum[1] \cite{1}

$\,$

$\,$

\begin{thebibliography}{99}

\bibitem{1} Spiegel, M. R. (1981). Theory and problems of Advanced Calculus: Si (metric) edition. McGraw-Hill. 

\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

I used a arXiv template for this, which is available on Overleaf.

When I use \section, it will show me an "undefined control sequence" error! Only if I use \section*, it will go away.

But I don't want to use \section*, because I want to have numbered sections (and also section-numbered definitions, theorems etc.).

How can I do this?

These are the error messages:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please show the complete first error message in your question (copy and paste it!)!

Comment: @Mensch I've added the error messages in the original post.

Comment: amsart is an article class and so doesn't know chapters. Don't use `\chaptertitlename\thechapter`.

Comment: Or if you want chapters, then use `amsbook` instead of `amsart`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use `amsart`, you should be aware of a few facts.

1. `titlesec` is not compatible with the class
2. `fancyhdr` might be compatible, but risky
3. the abstract should go before `\maketitle`
4. the class provides `\keywords`
5. the class has its own method for computing the type block once you set the desired height and width

I'm also not sure why changing `proof` in a way that's, to say the least, improper.

```
\documentclass[10pt,leqno]{amsart}
\usepackage{indentfirst,csquotes}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsthm,amsmath}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{paralist}
%\usepackage{titlesec} % <--- NOT WITH amsart
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{lipsum}

% this is wrong with amsart
%\topmargin= .5cm
%\textheight= 20cm
%\textwidth= 32cc
%\baselineskip=16pt
%\evensidemargin= .9cm
%\oddsidemargin= .9cm
%%% end wrong

\setlength{\textheight}{20cm}
\setlength{\textwidth}{32cc}
\calclayout
\linespread{1.33} % if you really want 16pt

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[]
\newtheorem{definition}[theorem]{Definition}
\newtheorem{example}[theorem]{Example}
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition}
\newtheorem{corollary}[theorem]{Corollary}
\newtheorem{conjecture}[theorem]{Conjecture}

%%% NOT with amsasrt
%\titleformat{\section}[display]
%  {\normalfont\huge\bfseries\centering}
%  {\centering\chaptertitlename\thechapter}
%  {10pt}
%  {\Large}
%\titlespacing*{\section}{0pt}{0ex}{0ex}
%%% end wrong

\hypersetup{ colorlinks=true, linkcolor=black, filecolor=black, urlcolor=black }

%%% DON'T redefine proof like this
%\def\proof{\noindent {\it Proof. $\, $}}
%\def\endproof{\hfill $\Box$ \vskip 5 pt }


\begin{document}

\title{Title}
\author[Initial Surname]{Author}
\date{\today}
\address{Address}
\email{example@mail.com}

\begin{abstract}
Abstract 
\end{abstract}

\keywords{MSC2020: Primary 00A05, Secondary 00A66.}

\maketitle

\section{Basic definitions}

\lipsum[1][1-4] \cite{1}

\begin{theorem}
Some text
\end{theorem}

\begin{proof}
This is the proof
\end{proof}

\lipsum[2][1-4]


\begin{thebibliography}{99}

\bibitem{1} Spiegel, M. R. (1981). Theory and problems of Advanced Calculus: 
Si (metric) edition. McGraw-Hill. 

\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want to customize the section titles to your liking, don't use `amsart`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Small question: How can I change the color of [1] to black instead of green?

Comment: @S-F `citecolor=black`, I'd say. But if you don't want to color links, do `colorlinks=false`. OK, this would draw red rectangles around them on some previewers. On the other hand, if all links are colored black, nobody would see them: just don't load `hyperref`.

Answer (score 0):

This template seems awful, find another one, or better just start afresh from

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\end{document}
```

and modify as necessary.

The error you're seeing is coming from `\titleformat{\section}[display]{\normalfont\huge\bfseries\centering}{\centering\chaptertitlename\thechapter}{10pt}{\Large}` and you can reproduce it with just

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}[display]{\normalfont\huge\bfseries\centering}{\centering\chaptertitlename\thechapter}{10pt}{\Large}
\begin{document}
\section{Bar}
\end{document}
```

`\section` is being configured to use chapter-specific macros in a class that doesn't support chapters.

On top of this it needlessly loads `fancyhdr` and `etoolbox`, defines an environment with

```
\def\proof{\noindent {\it Proof. $\, $}}
\def\endproof{\hfill $\Box$ \vskip 5 pt }
```

which is at least semantically less satisfying than `\[re]newenivronment` and uses the deprecated `\it`, and globally removes footnote labels with `\let\thefootnote\relax`.